# Java Selenium - Bypass driver.get() waiting time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to access a website using Selenium WebDriver, but the website will keep loading although I can still interact with it. (The website is nitrotype.com if you are wondering.) I think it is because `driver.get()` waits until the page is fully loaded. Can I bypass this until just a certain element loads ?

TL;DR
How do I bypass the `driver.get()` waiting until a site is completely loaded before proceeding?

Comment: what do you mean by `website will keep loading` ? I tried and can interact with it right away.

Comment: The website will keep loading, but you can interact with it before it finishes loading.

Answer (score 0):

Look into page load strategy: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/
Normal, Eager & None are your options. I suggest you combine your strategy with the proper explicit wait.

**NORMAL**

> normal This will make Selenium WebDriver to wait for the entire page
> is loaded. When set to normal, Selenium WebDriver waits until the load
> event fire is returned.
>
> By default normal is set to browser if none is provided.

**EAGER**

> eager This will make Selenium WebDriver to wait until the initial HTML
> document has been completely loaded and parsed, and discards loading
> of stylesheets, images and subframes.
>
> When set to eager, Selenium WebDriver waits until DOMContentLoaded
> event fire is returned.

**NONE**

> none When set to none Selenium WebDriver only waits until the initial
> page is downloaded.

To implement:

```
public class pageLoadStrategy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        try {
            // Navigate to Url
            driver.get("https://google.com");
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```